# +and+ in the URL resets the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

When we do a search, we pass the search value/parameters via QueryString.

When the search contains the word "AND", the connection is being reset.

This is because the QueryString formed looks something like this and is causing the connection to reset or the for the server to refuse the request:

search?value=high+and+dry

I tried to change the + to a %20 but I'm running to a different issue (tried using both HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode and Uri.EscapeDataString.

When I get to the search page, the URL is displayed as:

search?value=high and dry

The problem with that is if the user does a search again, the URL goes back to:

search?value=high+and+dry

Any thoughts or suggestions for a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this client-side script that is creating the URL and query string value or is it server-side code?

Comment: Actually the value is being set server-side. I tried using UrlPathEncode and Uri.EscapeDataString. By using those, I was able to convert the + to a %20 but I encountered a different issue (please see above)

Comment: Did you find any solution or reason for this?  We have the same problem.